# What could be blocking communication with TDA7706S on a Sony GT520U radio?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, frequency-modulation

I have a Sony GT520U radio which started developing a lot of noise and becoming unresponsive when in tuner mode. Opening it revealed the chipset on the tuner was overheating in less than 3 minutes of being switched to the tuner.

[image: The tuner board]

I figured out the receiver chipset is TDA7706s, I ordered a new one(only the IC) and replaced it, however, there seems to be no communication between the mainboard and the tuner board; because it starts at FM 87.50 MHz on the display, pressing the tune buttons changes to other predefined(or what it had in memory already) frequencies with no audio output - which behaves the same way when the tuner board is not mounted.

Looking at the connectors, it has SCL and SDA which means it uses I2C communication. In an effort to "debug", I connected Arduino to the mainboard via the I2C pins with the ground and ran a small snippet of code to scan and determine which address the mainboard is connecting, which it found to be 0x61. I proceeded to upload a different snippet to the Arduino to print out anything that was received on the I2C via the found address.

[image]

Here, it prints out *q ⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮* followed by 7 line breaks before repeating the same characters(each character on its own line) over and over again.

I expected to see some commands depending on what I inputted on the controls in the faceplate, but that was what came out.

When I power the tuner board with the required 8.5v and use Arduino to connect via I2C and scan for the connecting address, I get either 0x61 or 0x64 at different times, I needed to send some commands to it but have not found any useful reference for the commands.

Could it be possible the microcontroller on the mainboard is not sending the commands as expected?

How better can I debug the connection?

A few things to note:

- At first, when I connected the Arduino to the tuner board, it could not detect any I2C devices connected to it, after probing with a multimeter for continuity, I found out there was no continuity between the pins for SDA & SCL on the tuner board connector and the pins indicated on the actual IC in its datasheet([found here on page 4](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/tda7706.pdf)) - so I replaced 2 of the resistors to ones that gave me continuity.
- The current tools I have are a multimeter, hot air & soldering gun.

Comment: I learned that a new TDA7706 comes blank and needs firmware to be uploaded to it before it can be used(I found something I believe to be what is required but have no idea of how to upload it - https://github.com/NXP/mwifiex-firmware/blob/master/TDA7706_OM_v3.0.2_boot.txt)

I got a secondhand chipset from a different board and it worked well without issues.